# Separar archivos kotlin de los de java en android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy intentando crear un paquete aparte para separar los archivos de java y kotlin. Al inicar un proyecto en android la estructura es la siguiente:

```
app
 manifest
 java
  nombre.paquete.custom
 res
```

Mi objetivo es crear otro directorio que se llame **kotlin**  colocar alli el codigo correspondiente a kotlin

```
app
 manifest
 java
  nombre.paquete.custom
 kotlin
  nombre.paquete.custom
 res
```

leyendo la documentacion encontre esto: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin?hl=es#source

```
android {
   sourceSets {
       main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
   }
}
```

Esto fue lo que hice,  pero no logro hacerlo funcionar, porque al intentar crear una archivo dentro del directorio kotlin, el archivo se crear por defecto en el directorio java.

```
android{
  sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
        main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es, como es la manera correcta ó recomendada para separa el codigo java y kotlin?
Muchas gracias por sus opiniones!!

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor lo que intentas lograr? Por qué no lo dejaste como estaba en la documentación?

Comment: Para que deseas separarlo? solo para que no estén juntos? :-|

Comment: Para no mezclar el codigo java y kotlin, la idea es separalo. Al inicia un proyecto en android hay un directorio que dice Java, la idea era poder crear otro directorio que diga Kotlin, y colocar en cada directorio el codigo de cada lenguaje.

Comment: No es buena razón. Se supone que debes separar el código por funcionalidad o por capas. Aunque suene contraintuitivo, crear una carpeta kotlin en realidad es mezclar código. Además de que rompería la estructura de directorios. Ni siquiera sé si es posible tener el mismo paquete en dos carpetas diferentes. Pero si lo fuera, sería algo que deberías evitar a toda costa.

Comment: Estás migrando a kotlin o por qué usas dos lenguajes?